# Using "however" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Can I rephrase this sentence

> Our school only has Apple computers; however, some students are more
>   familiar with PCs.

to this one without changing the meaning?

> However, our school only has Apple computer; some students are more
>   familiar with PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as a standalone sentence. "However" can be used at the start of a sentence, but in that case it is indicating a contrast with something in a previous sentence, not with something later in teh same sentence. "However" can often be replaced with "but". If that makes no sense, the use of "however" may be incorrect.

You could, however, recast the sentence as:

> Even though our school only has Apple computers, some students are more familiar with PCs.

Exception (to "however"="but"): there is another sense of 'however" as in:

> However you do it, you must get it done.

Here "however" does not mean 'but" but rather 'in whatever way" or 'by whatever method", but that is not the case in the example in the question.

Comment: I was thinkig I could use "however" just like "although". Thank you

Comment: @tal they have, in a sense, opposite meanings. If you can say "X, however Y" you can **usually* say "Although Y, X" Note the reversed order.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Can't I say "Although X,Y" in this case as well?

Comment: @tal Not with the same meaning. I'll try to add some specific examples to the answer when I have a bit more time.

Comment: That would be great :)